# Getting substring of props value - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a class and I'm pulling in a props value

```
class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
     var value = this.props.value;
```

This works fine, and I get the value I want (it's a string - I checked with the typeof function).

However, now I want to take a substring of the value:

```
class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
     var value = this.props.value.substring(0,2);
```

I get an error saying *Cannot read property 'substring' of null*

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you do this: `var value = this.props.value;` ... `var valueTwo = value.substring(0, 2)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have [default props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values) for, just set your prop to an empty string as default.

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
   return {
       value: ''
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks *JordanHendrix*, your post made me realize what's going on. If I just pass in a string through props, then the substring method works fine.

But in reality I have a ReactiveDict that pulls values, tracks changes on them, and passes them into props, and so when the page loads, a null object is initially passed in to my *Body Class* until it's updated to the correct value. This initial null value is what's causing the substring method to mess up, and so I need to put in a check for that.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether prop value null or not before substring

```
 this.props.value && this.props.value.substring(0,2)
```